# How to insert PDF files in to sqlite. from my local system to Sqlite db

Tags: ios, pdf, sqlite

I have implemented an app in iphone using sqlite DB

I have 200 + PDF file to be used in application

***`I thought its better to store those files in sqlite and use them from here than copy them in to xcode project.`***

is my openion is correct or not.

If yes

then **how should i insert these 200+ PDF files to sqlite DB  from my system**.

Comment: Why not putting all PDF directly in application ? If size constraint is there than your DB will be too heavy if you are not downloading from server.

Comment: Assuming the PDF files are read-only, There is no reason to store the PDF files in the database. Use the filesystem for files. If anything, you can store the filename of the PDF files in the database but keep the PDF files in the app's resource bundle.